# Asp MVC routing per customer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a project in MVC 3 and I want to provide a specific url per customer.

Sample:

www.mysite.com/CustomerOne

www.mysite.com/CustomerTwo

.

I had already registered all routes and it worked well.

The problem is: I have to expect in all actions a first parameter for the customer name.

I'd like something like, having a property on a custom controller that tells me what customer is there.

Code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PerCustomer", // Route name
    "{customer}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", customer = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string customer)
    {
        //do stuff
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SaveSomething(string customer, string param1, ...)
    {
        //save stuff for the customer
        return View();
    }
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: I think what you are talking about is actually keeping customer state across multiple requests.  You must use the URL or hidden form fields if you do not keep that value in the session state.  Can you elaborate a bit how you want the URL scheme to look while keeping track of the customer?  There are a few ways to solve these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a BaseControoler class like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
     public string CurrentCustomer
     {
        get
        {
            return (string)RouteData.Values["customer"];
        }
     }
}
```

and in your controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController 
{ 
    public ActionResult Index() 
    { 
        //do stuff 
        DoSomethinwWith(this.CurrentCustomer);
        return View(); 
    } 

    public ActionResult SaveSomething(string param1, ...) 
    { 
        DoSomethinwWith(this.CurrentCustomer);
        return View(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Base controller implementations should be abstract to avoid unintentionally creating routes on every controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something that [should be modelbound](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx), or even better, you should place an [ActionFilter](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/03/12/asp-net-mvc-framework-2-interception-and-creating-a-role-action-filter.aspx) on your Controller, to make sure that customers from one company aren't getting into customer's from another company's stuff.

Without knowing more about your problem (e.g., what information each customer has, and if that's kept in the ASP.NET Membership system, or some other system, it'd be tougher to tell you what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PerCustomer", // Route name
    "/Profile/{customer}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", customer = UrlParameter.Optional, action = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

That will allow you to do /profile/Customer1 for view mode and /profile/customer1/edit for editing the customer. Becuase you need some sort of unique path element to identify distinctly from all other routers.

I hope this will help you